# How to find unmatched records in a single table?

Tags: sql, informix

I'm scraping a log file for transaction records that I am inserting into a table that will be used for several mining tasks. Each record has (among other things) an ID and a transaction type, either request or response. A request/response pair will have the same ID.

One of my tasks is to find all of the requests that do not have a corresponding response. I thought about joining the table to itself, where A.ID = B.ID AND A.type = 'req' and B.type = 'res', but that gives me the opposite of what I need.

Since the IDs will always occur either once or twice, is there a query that would select ID where there is only one occurrence of that ID in the table?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM the_table A WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM the_table B where A.ID = B.ID AND A.type = 'req' and B.type = 'res');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common type of query.  You can try aggregating over the `ID` values in your table using `GROUP BY`, then retaining those `ID` which appear only once.

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

If you also want to return the entire records for those `ID` occurring only once, you could try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID FROM yourTable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

The straight-forward way is `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from mytable
where type = 'req'
and id not in (select id from mytable where type = 'res');
```

You can write about the same with `NOT EXISTS`, but the query becomes slightly less readable:

```
select *
from mytable req
where type = 'req'
and not exists (select * from mytable res where type = 'res' and res.id = req.id);
```

And then there are forms of aggregation you can use, e.g.:

```
select *
from mytable
where type = 'req'
and id in 
(
  select id 
  from mytable 
  group by id 
  having count(case when type = 'res' then 1 end) = 0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the ones that have Request but not respose

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table A LEFT OUTER JOIN
your_table B ON A.ID = B.ID 
AND A.type = 'req' and B.type = 'res'
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Now I'm showing my SQL ignorance - if joining on A.ID = B.ID, how can B.ID then be NULL and A.ID not be NULL?

Comment: This is the LEFT JOIN, you will match A.ID = B.ID on the join level, so if there are records the WHERE statement will be false and will not select that record because it actually has a type = req. but if it does not have type=req then no records from table B will be selected which means B.ID is null

Comment: @Jim: This is called an anti join. It is mainly used in weak DBMS that have problems with straight-forward methods (namely `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`).